# ezfind installation

Tags: ezpublish

I have installed ezpublish, and ezcomponent placed in lib/ezc.

*Now, i want to install ez find. i have  followed 3 steps according to install.txt (that present in ezfind folder)

In the fourth step i given like follows,

> php d:/wamp/www/epub/bin/php/ezpgenerateautoloads.php

when the following error occurs.

PHP Warning:  require(Base/src/base.php): failed to open stream: No such fil directory in D:\wamp\www\epub\bin\php\ezpgenerateautoloads.php on line 48

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this script from the root of your eZ Publish installation, which would be in your case, if I am not mistaken :

```
cd d:/wamp/www/epub/
php bin/php/ezpgenerateautoloads.php
```

Comment: I ran this command, but error message occurs like,

'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: But this error did not occur in the first place it seems. Is the PHP executable in your Path ?